# How to report GPA, if minimum letter grade credits not reached?

Tags: funding, gpa

How would a graduate student, at the University of California, Santa Cruz, report their GPA, on fellowship applications, if they have not yet accrued enough letter grade credits?

UCSC seems to not report a formal GPA until the student takes 25 credits of letter grade classes. This excludes credits received from pass / fail classes, which count toward graduation but not toward the 25 credit letter grade GPA threshold.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems the National Defense Science and Engineering Graduate (NDSEG) Fellowship states:

> What GPA do I enter for my school if I just started attending? You can
>   enter 0.0 as your GPA – reviewers will understand that you have not
>   yet received a GPA for that school and will not view it negatively.
>   Link: https://ndseg.asee.org/faq/academic_background_section

Will follow-up if I receive any formal statement from the UCSC Office of the Registrar.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of whether you have a "formal" GPA or not, you can always calculate your GPA yourself. You know what grades you received and you should know how your school weighs each one. There are also many "GPA calculator" sites online that can help with this.